# Mysql syntax error (mysql noob here)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

```
DELIMITER ||

CREATE FUNCTION InsertEvent (IN iPatientMonitoringId BIGINT, 
                             IN iTypeId SMALLINT(6), 
                             IN iChannelId SMALLINT(6), 
                             IN iStart TIMESTAMP, 
                             IN iEnd TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS BIGINT DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Event 
    (Id, PatientMonitoringId, TypeId, ChannelId, StartOcurrence, EndOcurrence)
  VALUES 
    ('', iPatientMonitoringId, iTypeId, iChannelId, iStart, iEnd);

  RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();

END ||

DELIMITER ;
```

This sql query looks ok to me but I'm not understanding the error returned by phpmyadmin:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN iPatientMonitoringId BIGINT, IN

Comment: It's saying it doesn't like the IN. I'm not sure if something should go before it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

```
Note
Specifying a parameter as IN, OUT, or INOUT is valid only for a PROCEDURE. 
For a FUNCTION, parameters are always regarded as IN parameters.
```

Therefore, I believe you should drop the IN.

Try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION InsertEvent (iPatientMonitoringId BIGINT, iTypeId SMALLINT(6), 
iChannelId SMALLINT(6), iStart TIMESTAMP, iEnd TIMESTAMP) RETURNS BIGINT 
DETERMINISTIC
```

Comment: I should read the entire thing, the beginning just says: `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_name ([parameter[,...]])
[characteristic ...] routine_body

CREATE FUNCTION sp_name ([parameter[,...]])
[RETURNS type]
[characteristic ...] routine_body

parameter:
  [ IN | OUT | INOUT ] param_name type
...
`